# Predicting position given constant angular + linear acceleration with a non-fixed axis

Tags: acceleration, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

My readings on rotational motion always describes rotation around a fixed axis: that is, an object on a string, basically, and changes to angular velocity will alter speed such that the radius is fixed.

What kind of reading should I be doing to understand rotational motion where the axis isn't fixed? Like, an object is moving with velocity $\vec v$ and constant speed $\Vert v \Vert$ but $ω_t = ω_0 + αt$... what do I need to be looking at to determine its position at time $t$? And, by extension, cases where $v_f = v_0 + at$?

My assumption is that this is some kind of integral but I can't get my head around it.